# Creating a fancy calculation for price in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 prices:

Price1: $5000
Price2: $2000

What I want is JavaScript to calculate the total live on the page, so when the div loads, that it starts calculating.

But I don't just want to instantly see $7000 right there. I want it to 'animate' the result. So go from $0 to $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 ... $5000, $5001, $5002 ... $7000.

I also want the price that it's currently adding below the line that's adding to.

EX:

> Total: $TOTALPRICE
>
> Currently adding: Price1

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Have you tried making any progress on this?

Comment: @smerny I've got no idea on how to do this. So no, because I'll probably do something completely wrong.

Comment: Of course it's possible; loop, add, display. There are many ways this could be done, though, and the "best" depends on your requirements, how your page code is generally shaped, etc.

Comment: You could use some sort of recursion which adds each total and updates per add.

Comment: @MrDikke So what if you do something "completely wrong"?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript, could anyone please provide me with a small example?

Comment: get something completely wrong, get stuck, then come for help... you'll learn more... and who knows, you might surprise yourself

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, it starts of by not knowing how to achieve this, then shortage of much Javascript experience then probably making it way harder for myself then making a mess and have to end up deleting it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery lets you [`.animate()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) any arbitrary value.
Access the current animated  `now` value using the `step` method callback

```js
var tot  = 0,
    $p1  = $("#p1"),
    $p2  = $("#p2"),
    $tot = $("#tot");

function animateTotal() {

  tot = parseFloat($p1.val()) + parseFloat($p2.val());

  $({ p: 0 }).animate({ p: tot }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "swing",   // "swing" is default, you can try another easing like "linear"
    step: function (now) {
      $tot.val( now.toFixed(2) );
    }
  });

}

$p1.add($p2).on("input", animateTotal);
$p1.trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$<input value="3000.50" id="p1" name="p1">PRICE1 +<br>
$<input value="4000" id="p2" name="p1">PRICE2 =<br>
$<input value="0" readonly id="tot" name="tot">
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the UI as you add

Maybe try something like:

(JQuery)

```
var existing = 0;

var numbersToAdd = [ 1, 30, 40];


$.each(numbersToAdd, function(i, e) {
   fancyAdd(e, existing);
});

function fancyAdd(n, existing) {
    $('#idOfResultDiv').innerHTML = n + existing;
   existing = n + existing;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="idOfResultDiv"></div>
```

You can also use `setTimeout` to delay execution

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle working here : https://jsfiddle.net/v7n7fscv/

Try this code You will need a self invoking function because setTimeout() function is non blocking & will not block the for loop to be executed :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js
"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result">

    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var a = 20;
    var b = 20;

    c = a+b;

    var counter = 0;
    (function next() {
        if (counter++ >= c) return;

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#result").html(counter);
            next();
        }, 0.00001);
    })();

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I want. But as you can see in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/dszbafst/) I'm talking about numbers that are bigger than you are showing there. And it's taking ages to get to the end. I already added 0 to the setTimeout, but you were at the max. Anyway of making this faster?

Comment: yeah decrease the value of time out delay something like 0.00000001.

Comment: At that point the js wouldn't even really be able to process that fast anyway. It would be best to increment by larger numbers when the difference is bigger

Comment: yeah give me a sec, I am updating the fiddle for u.

Comment: You can keep adding conditions for 100, 10 etc.